# Video Sequence Editor Cursor Offset

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm using VSE for all of my editing, but I encountered a display issue since few days.
There is an offset between the green cursor and the cursor exact position.
So I can't visually know where I'm in the timeline when i cut my clips.

thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you Remapped the Time of your project? Are the parameters 100/100 or something like 100/101? You can find the values in the Dimension panel in the Render tab of the Properiest editor; It's the one where you set the FPS, the size of the frame...

Comment: Wow!! Thank you Carlo this was my problem. Time remapping old value was 99 though new was 100. Thank you so much.